# lambda>() missing

Tags: python

me genera error lamba pero no se como corregirlo

```
    etiquetadosSinProcesar = filter(lambda nodo, _: not nodo in procesados, etiquetas.items())
    return min(etiquetadosSinProcesar, key=lambda _, acum, __: acum)[0]
```

[image: me sale este error pero no se como manejarlo]

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos. Antes de poder ayudarte, deberías incluir el código en formato texto, no como imagen, ya que así es fácil leerlo, copiarlo y probarlo. Además el título de la prgunta debe ser descriptivo del problema. Te recomiendo que mires [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más información.

Comment: La respuesta de @Dante S. es perfecta. Pero si tienes curiosidad puedes leer esta pregunta con su respuesta que he escrito a partir de tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/525617/7123

Answer (score 2):

Cuando funciones como `filter` y `min` recorren un iterador o un iterable, las funciones que les pases deben recibir un solo argumento (que será lo devuelto por el iterador o iterable). En el caso de los items de un diccionario, el argumento enviado será una tupla de la forma `(clave, valor)`.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, la primera línea de tu código debería de ser:

```
etiquetadosSinProcesar = filter(lambda key_and_value: key_and_value[0] not in procesados, etiquetas.items())
```

Esto nos devolverá un iterador que cuando lo recorramos nos irá devolviendo las tuplas `(clave, valor)` filtradas.

Esas tuplas será lo que recibirá el segundo lambda, por lo que tendremos que aplicar la misma logica en dicho:

```
return min(etiquetadosSinProcesar, key=lambda key_and_value:key_and_value[1])[0]
```