# Desempaquetar argumentos en una lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, programación-funcional

A raíz de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/525528/7123) se me ocurre una pregunta nueva. Voy a dar antes un poco de contexto:

Cuando usas `filter()` u otras funciones como `min()`, `max()`, `sort()`, `map()`, que admiten una lambda como parámetro, Python invocará a la función lambda pasándole un solo parámetro. Incluso si los elementos sobre los que se están iterando son tuplas, Python no hace el *desempaquetado* automático (lo hacía en la versión 2 pero esa funcionalidad ha sido eliminada en Python3)

Es decir, imagina que tienes una lista que contiene tuplas de tres datos como esta:

```
mi_lista = [ (1, 2, 3), (2, 0, 5), (3, 4, 8), (10, 1, 2) ]
```

y quieres usar `filter` para quedarte sólo con las tuplas cuyo segundo elemento sea menor que 2. Podrías pensar en hacer algo así (y en Python 2 funcionaría, aunque tendrías que poner `(x,y,z)` entre paréntesis:

```
for elegido in filter(lambda x,y,z: y<2, mi_lista):
    print(elegido)
```

Pero eso no funciona en Python3 y nos vemos obligados a poner:

```
for elegido in filter(lambda tupla: tupla[1]<2, mi_lista):
    print(elegido)
```

Y en este caso sí, el resultado sería `(2, 0, 5)` y `(10, 1, 2)`

La verdad es que en el ejemplo anterior, al ser tan abstracto, lo mismo nos da escribir `tupla[1]<2` que `y<2`, pero en algunos casos el poder poner nombre al parámetro puede ayudar a la legibilidad. Por ejemplo, si cada elemento de la tupla tiene un significado muy preciso, y el segundo campo es por ejemplo la edad, es más legible poner `edad<18` que `tupla[1]<18`.

Entonces ¿podemos escribir una lambda que reciba varios parámetros con nombre en su declaración e implementación, pero que pueda ser usada como argumento en un `filter()` (o similares) que le va a pasar un solo parámetro?

Answer (score 3):

Una solución: redefinir `filter` de modo que llame a lambda con los parámetros desempaquetados:

```
mi_lista = [ (1, 2, 3), (2, 0, 5), (3, 4, 8), (10, 1, 2) ]

def tfilter(f, ite):
    for x in ite:
        if f(*x):
            yield x

for elegido in tfilter(lambda x, y, z: y < 2 , mi_lista):
    print(elegido)
```

produce:

```
(2, 0, 5)
(10, 1, 2)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Solución general

En lugar de crear una nueva versión de `filter`, esta otra solución permite desempaquetar directamente el lambda:

```
def unpack(tup, *vars):
    i = 0
    for x in tup:
        setattr(unpack, vars[i], x)
        i += 1
    return unpack
```

La función recibe una tupla y un numero variable de argumentos con los nombres de los campos deseados. Los valores son extraidos de la tupla y guardados como atributos de la función. La función se retorna a si misma, por lo que luego puedo extraer los campos por nombre.

**Demo**

```
mi_lista = [ (1, 2, 3), (2, 0, 5), (3, 4, 8), (10, 1, 2) ]

def unpack(tup, *vars):
    i = 0
    for x in tup:
        setattr(unpack, vars[i], x)
        i += 1
    return unpack

for elegido in filter(lambda tup: unpack(tup, "x", "y", "z").y < 2 , mi_lista):
    print(elegido)
```

produce:

```
(2, 0, 5)
(10, 1, 2)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Esto funciona incluso si queremos usar más de un campo. Por ejemplo, queremos `y < 2` y `x == 10`:

```
for elegido in filter(lambda tup: unpack(tup, "x", "y", "z").y < 2 and unpack.x == 10 , mi_lista):
    print(elegido)
```

Funciona pues la función `unpack` mantiene sus atributos hasta una nueva invocación.

Comment: Es una buena idea (+1) y queda mucho más legible que mi "solución", pero no es exactamente lo que preguntaba, pues yo buscaba cómo pasar a filter una función que pudiera recibir varios parámetros, más que cómo modificar filter para que acepte una función así.

Comment: @abulafia. Tienes razón; agregue una solución más general.

Comment: No me convence la solución más general. Si la función va a ser usada varias veces, la memoria se sobrecargaría de valores que ya no se usan, pero no son eliminados por que aun tienen referencias. En resumen, quedarían atributos basura. En lo personal yo usaría un namedtuple.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ha ocurrido la siguiente solución, más como un reto personal que como algo verdaderamente útil, pero he decidido escribirlo de todas formas por si alguien lo considera útil, o aprende un truco nuevo que pueda usar en otro contexto.

Preparamos la siguiente función:

```
from functools import partial
def unpacked_call(x, f):
  return f(*x)
```

Y ahora ya podríamos invocar a `filter` en la forma siguiente:

```py
for elegido in filter(partial(unpacked_call, f=lambda x,y,z: y<2), mi_lista):
    print(elegido)
---
(2, 0, 5)
(10, 1, 2)
```

### Explicación

La función `unpacked_call()` recibe como primer parámetro `x` que es una tupla con cualquier número de elementos, y como segundo parámetro `f` que es una función cualquiera (y puede ser una lambda). Internamente se limita a ejecutar `f(*x)`, lo que produce el **desempaquetado** de `x`, es decir, que sus elementos se pasan como parámetros individuales y separados a `f`.

La función `partial` (del módulo `functools`) recibe como parámetro obligatorio una función (digamos `mi_funcion`) y como parámetros opcionales otros, posicionales o con nombres (digamos por ejemplo `foo=bar`). Lo que hace es retornarte otra función a la que puedes llamar con menos parámetros de los que necesitarías pasarle a `mi_funcion`, pues parte de los parámetros que ésta recibía estarán ya rellenados, en el ejemplo `foo` estaría ya rellenado con el valor `bar`.

En mi solución hago `partial(unpacked_call, f=lambda x, y, z: ...)` por lo que ocurre aquí lo siguiente:

- `partial` recibe la función `unpacked_call` y el argumento `f`
- `partial` retorna entonces una nueva función que espera ya un solo parámetro, y que internamente invocará `unpacked_call(parametro, f=lambda x,y,z: ...)`
- Esa función es la que usará `filter()` en cada iteración, y la llamará pasándole la tupla que corresponda. Eso causará que se ejecute `unpacked_call()` recibiendo como primer parámetro la tupla en cuestión y como segundo parámetro la lambda
- `unpacked_call()`, al hacer `f(*x)`, invocará la lambda desempaquetando la tupla.

Misión conseguida!

Answer (score 2):

#### Problemas con la solución general de otra respuesta (perdon, no tengo intención de ofender)

Esta respuesta se ofrece como una alternativa a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/525621/158880). Me disculpo por cualquier ofensa, no es la intención. La solución general ofrecida allí, a pesar de ser muy bonita, tiene un problema. Si queremos usar esa función en otros casos, quedarían guardados los atributos de los casos anteriores.

Por ejemplo si aplicasemos:

```
def unpack(tup, *vars):
    i = 0
    for x in tup:
        setattr(unpack, vars[i], x)
        i += 1
    return unpack

list(filter(lambda tup: unpack(tup, "x", "y", "z").y < 2 , mi_lista))
list(filter(lambda tup: unpack(tup, "a", "b", "c").b < 2 , mi_lista))
```

La función unpack se quedaría con los atributos `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, `b` y `c`. Y así, si se usa muy seguido, seguiría recolectando estos "atributos basura", cuyos valores a los que referencian no serían recolectados por el recolector de basura de Python, ya que la unica forma de borrar estos atributos sería hacerlo manualmente o borrando la propia función en sí.

#### Explicación sobre una alternativa similar

Yo creo que lo más conveniente sería usar el objeto [namedtuple](https://rico-schmidt.name/pymotw-3/collections/namedtuple.html) del modulo collections.

`namedtuple` nos devuelve un objeto especial al cual si le pasamos los items de un iterable como argumentos, nos crea otro objeto especial que funciona similar a una tupla, pero podemos acceder a sus items usando atributos, además del modo convencional.

###### Ejemplo

```
import collections

Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name age')

jane = Person(name='Jane', age=29)
print('\nField by name:', jane.name)
```

###### Produce

```
Field by name: Jane
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta, podemos hacer una clase especial que cuando sea llamada convierta el argumento que reciba (asumiendo que será un iterable) en un namedtuple y llame a una función especifica pasando dicho namedtuple de argumento. Este objeto lo llamaremos Wrapper:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, named_tuple, callback):
        self.named_tuple = named_tuple
        self.callback = callback

    def __call__(self, item):
        return self.callback(self.named_tuple(*item))
```

Y una función que instancie a Wrapper y lo use en la función filter convencional:

```
def named_filter(tupla_nombrada, callback, iterable):
    return filter(Wrapper(tupla_nombrada, callback), iterable)
```

#### La alternativa en practica

###### Código

```
from collections import namedtuple

dic = dict(a=0, b=1, c=2)

tupla_nombrada = namedtuple("dict_items", ("key", "value"))

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, named_tuple, callback):
        self.named_tuple = named_tuple
        self.callback = callback

    # Cuando un objeto es llamado, internamente llama a esta función.
    def __call__(self, item):
        return self.callback(self.named_tuple(*item))

def named_filter(tupla_nombrada, callback, iterable):
    return filter(Wrapper(tupla_nombrada, callback), iterable)

print("Original", list(dic.items()))
print("Filtrado", list(named_filter(tupla_nombrada, lambda x:x.value, dic.items())))
```

###### Produce

```
Original [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
Filtrado [('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

#### Otra alternativa mejor

Por supuesto, la mejor alternativa de todas, es la comprensión de generador junto al [unpacking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961), que nos da más personalización a la hora de recorrer un iterable.

La primera linea del código que di en la pregunta referenciada, puede pasarse a comprensión de generador:

###### Original

```
etiquetadosSinProcesar = filter(lambda key_and_value: key_and_value[0] not in procesados, etiquetas.items())
```

###### Usando comprensión de generador

```
etiquetadosSinProcesar = ((key, value) for key, value in etiquetas.items() if(key not in procesados))
```

Más información sobre esto en https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/